# How to use the dropbox api correctly on localhost?

Tags: java, dropbox

I am using dropbox core api.

```
// Get files and folder metadata from Dropbox root directory
        public static ListFolderResult listFiles(DbxClientV2 client) throws DbxException {
            ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolder("");
            while (true) {
                for (Metadata metadata : result.getEntries()) {
                    System.out.println(metadata.getPathLower());
                }    
                if (!result.getHasMore()) {
                    break;
                }    
                result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Now the user should be able to list all folders on localhost via `/list`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need first to autheticate the user to dropbox using the dropbox java api

Please look at this, here is everything described clearly [Dropbox JAVA API](https://javapapers.com/java/dropbox-java-api-tutorial/)

Comment: The client that I pass to the method already is the registered one. But how do I do it with localhost:8080/list ?

Comment: Are you developing a native app or a rest api ?

Comment: If you can access to this URI : localhost/list you need only to Instantiate the Dropbox User in the constructor and make a call of ListFolderResult  function and pass the instance as a parameter